# Не отображается содержимое HTML

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Shop.Data.interfaces;
using Shop.Data.mocks;



namespace Shop
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                  
            services.AddTransient<IAllCars, MockCars>();
            services.AddTransient<ICarsCategory, MockCategory>();
            services.AddMvc(); // 
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            
           
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); 
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); 
            app.UseStatusCodePages(); 
            app.UseStaticFiles(); 
            
          
        }
    }
}
```

СarsController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Shop.Data.interfaces;
using Shop.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Shop.Controllers
{
    public class CarsController : Controller { // унаследовали от Класса Контролер

        private readonly IAllCars _allCars; // переменная на интерфей ( интерфейс+ класс с реализацией)
        private readonly ICarsCategory _allCategories;

        public CarsController(IAllCars iAllCars , ICarsCategory iCarsCat)
        {
            _allCars = iAllCars;
            _allCategories = iCarsCat;
        }
        public ViewResult List() { // обращаемся к ф-ции List и получаем html страничку
            ViewBag.Title = "Страница с автомобилями";
            CarsListViewModel obj = new CarsListViewModel();
            obj.allCars = _allCars.Cars;
            obj.currCategory = "Автомобили";

           
           return View(obj); // получение htlm
```

List.cshtml

```
 <h1>Все автомобили</h1>
    <h3>@Model.currCategory</h3>
    @{
        foreach (var car in Model.allCars)
        {
            <div>
                    <h2>Модель: @car.name</h2>
                <p>Цена:@car.price.ToString("c")</p>
              </div>

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ты отключил маршрутизацию по конечным точкам, ну так самой маршрутизации у тебя нет. Либо добавляй обработчик маршрута в методе configure, через метод расширения UseMvc, либо в самом контроллере через атрибуты пропиши путь, по типу

```
[Route("List")]
public IActionResult List()...
```